# WeakReference string didn't garbage collected? How?

Tags: java, weak-references

I'm reading about `WeakReference` in wikipedia and I saw this code

```
public class ReferenceTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            WeakReference r = new WeakReference(new String("I'm here"));
            WeakReference sr = new WeakReference("I'm here");

            System.out.println("before gc: r=" + r.get() + ", static=" + sr.get());
            System.gc();
            Thread.sleep(100);

            // only r.get() becomes null
            System.out.println("after gc: r=" + r.get() + ", static=" + sr.get());

        }
}
```

When It runs this is the result

> before gc: r=I'm here, static=I'm here
>
> after gc: r=null, static=I'm here

`sr` and `r` variable are both referring string objects. `r` is now garbage collected but, why `sr` didn't garbage collected after calling garbage collector?

I'm just curious how this happened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is **NOT** because of string pooling *per se*.

The real reason is that the `ReferenceTest` class has an implicit hard reference to the String object that represents the `"I'm here"`literal.  That hard reference means that the weak reference in `sr` won't be broken by the garbage collection<sup>1</sup>.

In fact:

- The implicit reference would be necessary, even if String objects corresponding to literals weren't pooled.  (They *are* pooled ... the JLS effectively *requires* this ... but I'm saying the references would required even if they weren't.  The alternative would be for Java to create and "intern" a fresh String object each time a string literal expression was evaluated.  That would be *horribly* inefficient!!)
- The string pool *internally* uses a form of weak reference ... so that unreferenced interned strings can be garbage collected.  If that weren't the case, then calling `String.intern()` would potentially be an incurable memory leak.

Anyway ... if you carefully construct a string without using a string literal and intern it, like this:

```
    char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    WeakReference r = new WeakReference(new String(chars).intern());
```

... you should find that the weak reference is (eventually) broken.  (It might take a couple of GC cycles though.)

---

<sup>1 - In theory, causing the class to be unloaded and garbage collected could get rid of the last reachable hard reference to that String literal.  However, if that happened in this case, you'd be past the point at which you'd be able to observe the state of the WeakReference object.  At least, in with your example code.  Besides, unless you boot your JVM with a custom class loader, I don't think it would be possible to cause the unloading of the entrypoint class.  It's not the kind of thing that is easy, or useful to do.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It is becuase of string pooling.When you create string with new operator, it will get created in pool and available for normal garbage collection.But when you define string as literal, it will get created in string pool, and it wont get garbage collected with normal gc operation

Comment: if I allocate a string in the pool. The string gets destroyed after the program is terminated?

Comment: Yes...After your program terminates, definitely the memory allocated will be gone

Comment: Yes ... but that's not *caused* by string pooling.  It is caused by the fact that the class has a hard reference to the String object that represents the string literal.

Answer (score -1):

Static variables are Garbage Collected only when the class is unloaded. Therefore you can see that the value of the static variable is still printed even after you manually triggered garbage collection.

Comment: but `sr` and `r` are both static variables.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the Strings don't become weakly reachable and then collected.  There are no static variables referring directly to either String instance.